# How to sample from a Gaussian process with only diagonal components of the covariance matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, diagonalization, covariance, sampling

This is related to the question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218718/how-do-we-sample-from-a-gaussian-process), where the answer is that $\boldsymbol{X} = \mu + A\boldsymbol{Z}$. Note that $\boldsymbol{X}$ is the n-dimensional sample we seek, $\mu$ is the mean vector, $\Sigma = AA^T$ is the covariance matrix, and $\boldsymbol{Z}=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)^T$ is a vector of independent, standard normal variables. Essentially, the necessary pieces are $\mu, \Sigma,$ and $\boldsymbol{Z}$.

What I am wondering is: if we have only $\mu, \text{diag}(\Sigma),$ and $\boldsymbol{Z}$, is there any way to still draw a sample $\boldsymbol{X}$? Below is a very simple example, and I am wondering if there is a way to sample from this mean function with corresponding standard deviation.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

def f(x):
    """arbitrary function"""
    return 1.5*(1. - np.tanh(100.*(x-0.96))) + 1.5*x*(x-0.95) + 0.4 + 0.01*(1.-x)* np.random.random(x.shape)

X = np.linspace(0.8,1.1,1000)

# Observations and noise
y = f(X).ravel() 
sigma = 0.2/y + 0.1*(1.-X) 

plt.figure()  
plt.plot(X, y, 'k-', label=u'mean')
plt.fill(np.concatenate([X, X[::-1]]),
         np.concatenate([y - 2. * sigma,
                        (y + 2. * sigma)[::-1]]),
         alpha=.1, fc='k', ec='None', label='2 standard deviations')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')  
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'll have to make a decision about those missing entries in the covariance matrix, and by extension the sort of function you want out. Choose them all zero and you'll get a function that is continuous nowhere. Choose something like the 'Orstein-Uhlenbeck exponential kernel' (referenced in the comments in your link) and you'll get something much more reasonable, continuous but not differentiable.